# Cookies not being remembered

Tags: jquery

I am using a 'be it old' stylesheet selector that works brilliantly and allows the user to select their stylesheet. However in the demo, the selection is remembered on a page refresh however on my version it is not.

The demo is [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm)

The days to store are set using the code below with 60 being the number of days.

```
<a href="javascript:chooseStyle('brown-theme', 60)">Brown theme</a>
```

In the JS plugin they are storing the cookies as so

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
var expireDate = new Date()
//set "expstring" to either future or past date, to set or delete cookie, respectively
var expstring=(typeof days!="undefined")? expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+parseInt(days)) : expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()-5)
document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; expires="+expireDate.toGMTString()+"; path=/";
}

function deleteCookie(name){
setCookie(name, "moot")
}
```

Any reason why this isn't working?

Comment: Where is your code for `chooseStyle`? maybe it isn't passing `60` the way it's supposed to.

Comment: i cant check it right now, but why are you adding number(int) to DateTime object? i think its illigal in JS and you need to use expireDate.getDate().AddDays(days)

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear, sorry, This is a plugin that they do this in. Im not 100% up with jQuery so not to sure